# C++\CLI backgroundworker passing multiple arguments

Tags: arguments, c++-cli, backgroundworker

I have an application with a ListView that contains some filenames and filepaths that I want to pass to a BackgroundWorker. I essentially want the worker thread to know the strings that this ListView contains one way or another.

While tinkering with this and searching around I have tried making a `public ref Class` so that I can send it to the `RunWorkerAsync()` function, which gives me a *can not convert to System::Object* error:

```
public ref class FileInfoContainer {
public:
    cli::array<System::String^>^ filepaths;
    cli::array<System::String^>^ filenames;
    System::String^ outfile;

    FileInfoContainer(cli::array<System::String^>^ filepaths, cli::array<System::String^>^ filenames, System::String^ outfile);
};
```

I have also tried passing the whole Form as an argument to `RunWorkerAsync()` which, during debugging, indeed passes every piece of data the Form has into a `System::Object`. The problem is that if I try to access an element of my form through this object I get a *not member of System::Object* error:

```
private: System::Void compworker_DoWork(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventArgs^  e) {
    BackgroundWorker^ worker = dynamic_cast<BackgroundWorker^>(sender);

    System::Object^ arg = e->Argument;
    arg->button1    //this fails

    MainForm form1 = (MainForm)e->Argument;  //this also fails, even though I've seen it suggested in numerous threads
}
```

Any good suggestions about how I can pass my arguments to the worker thread?

Comment: auto arg = safe_cast<FileInfoContainer^>(e->Argument);

Comment: @HansPassant in this case how can I pass the class as the argument to RunWorkerAsync()? It gives me the error I explained above